# Display JSON message from server on the screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, httprequest

In my flutter app, I am calling a function which sends a POST request to my server. What I want to happen, is if a field is forgotten for example, display the JSON message for that from my server.

Currently, this works however the JSON message is printed on my terminal, however I want the message displayed on my screen.

dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

class Third extends StatelessWidget {
  makePostRequest() async {
    final uri = 'https://infinite-sea-61086.herokuapp.com/api/users/signup';
    final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {'email': 'test550@gmail.com', 'password': 'test123456', 'confirmPassword': 'test123456'};
    String jsonBody = json.encode(body);
    final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');

    Response response = await post(
      uri,
      headers: headers,
      body: jsonBody,
      encoding: encoding,
    );

    int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    String responseBody = response.body;
    print(responseBody);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    makePostRequest();
    return new Center(
      child: new Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

An example of a message from server, being displayed on terminal (That I want displayed on the screen):

**flutter: "username" is required**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the `FutureBuilder` class to make the request between the widgets. I just updated your code, it must work.

```dart
class Third extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<String> makePostRequest() async {
    final uri = 'https://infinite-sea-61086.herokuapp.com/api/users/signup';
    final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {'email': 'test550@gmail.com', 'password': 'test123456', 'confirmPassword': 'test123456'};
    String jsonBody = json.encode(body);
    final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');

    Response response = await post(
      uri,
      headers: headers,
      body: jsonBody,
      encoding: encoding,
    );

    int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    String responseBody = response.body;
    print(responseBody);
    return responseBody;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    makePostRequest();
    return new Center(
      child: new Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: makePostRequest(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {

                if(snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data);
                }

                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When I implement this code, I get an error saying type Future<Dynamic> is not a subtype of type Future<String>.  An idea why this is.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with my function needing to return an async value, however I am not sure.

Comment: Yes. The function must have Future<String> as the return type as I did in my answer

Answer (score 0):

`print()` will print its argument on the console. Put your http response in a [Text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) widget instead.

In addition, you could wrap that Text widget in a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and pass your `makePostRequest()` as the future so that the response gets displayed once available. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo) might be helpful.

Comment: Instead of print, I have replaced it with Text(responseBody),  however nothing is being displayed on my screen.

Comment: I have also tried new Text() in my makePostRequest function, however nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: The text widget is supposed to go in your widget tree, inside the children list of your row for example